# Laravel 5 - Stuck between artisan clear-compiled and composer update

Tags: git, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I pulled changes from `origin` and it seems some provider from a new dependency was added to `config/app.php`. I know I'm supposed to run `composer update` in order to pull that dependency but since Laravel's default `composer.json` file appends `php artisan clear-compiled` beforehand, I can't really update cause `clear-compiled` is crashing due to the non-existing dependency.

What's the **right way** of fixing this? I know I could just delete the whole `vendor/` or quickly `comment/uncomment` the missing provider, but that seems more than a hackz rather than an actual procedure. Maybe the whole incident shouldn't have occurred at all and we should improve our git usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `composer update --no-scripts` to prevent running `clear-compiled` artisan command before update. I usually run above and then `php artisan optimize --force` when I delete a package.

Comment: this is a copout answer

Comment: @abbood copout?